# JQuery Add two selections together

Tags: javascript, jquery, selection

With the power of jquery...

I'm attempting to add two selections together, they both contain the same type of element (`<option>`).

But the `add(..)` method doesn't seem to be playing ball.

```
var matchingRemovedOptions = removedOptions.filter(function() {
  return this.text.toLowerCase().match(str.toLowerCase());
});
tempOptions.add(matchingRemovedOptions);
console.log(tempOptions.length);
console.log(matchingRemovedOptions.length);
```

As you can see im trying to filter out some option elements from the removedOptions selection and add these to the tempOptions selection.

But when using the console.log, the length of tempOptions stays the same as in, does not increase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) *returns* a set with the elements/selector added, it doesn't actually *add them to the set* that it's called on.  To get the effect you want, you need to update to the set it returns, like this:

```
tempOptions = tempOptions.add(matchingRemovedOptions);
```

If you think about all other [tree traversal functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/), they behave the same way, for example `obj.find("...")` doesn't change `obj` to what's found, only the *rest* of the chain operates on that set, which [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) *returns*.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do another assignation:

```
tempOptions = tempOptions.add(matchingRemovedOptions);
```

Comment: i cant believe it, as soon as i finished posting this message it dawned on me when i looked back at the code.